# Sum negative and positive numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sum

I'm using SQL Server 2008.  I've got sales for customers and I want to compare it to what the customer bought the previous year, also calculate the growth.  It all works fine but as soon as the customer has a negative for one of the months it brings back the wrong data for Target & Growth.

```
Customer     SalesLastYearMonth      SalesThisYearMonth      Target     Growth
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abcd         -1                      15                      ????       ???
```

Code:

```
SELECT
    Customer,
    CASE 
        WHEN SalesThisYearMonth IS NULL THEN (SalesLastYearMonth * -1)
        WHEN SalesLastYearMonth IS NULL THEN SalesThisYearMonth 
        ELSE SalesThisYearMonth -  SalesLastYearMonth END as Target,
    CASE 
        WHEN SalesThisYearMonth IS NULL THEN -1 
        WHEN SalesLastYearMonth IS NULL THEN 1 
        WHEN SalesThisYearMonth = 0 then -1
        WHEN SalesLastYearMonth = 0 then 1
        ELSE ( SalesThisYearMonth - SalesLastYearMonth) / SalesLastYearMonth END AS Growth
```

Comment: Can you give an example of error and expected output that you are not getting?

Comment: @Ivan G I'm getting the following:  Target:  16.000, Growth:  -16.000000

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: This is really fuzzy logic.  Can you share with us what you're trying to do?  What should the target and growth be .. in plain english.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want TARGET=16, GROWTH=16, then this should do it:

```
SELECT
    Customer,
    CASE 
        WHEN SalesThisYearMonth IS NULL THEN (SalesLastYearMonth * -1)
        WHEN SalesLastYearMonth IS NULL THEN SalesThisYearMonth 
        ELSE SalesThisYearMonth -  SalesLastYearMonth END as Target,
    CASE 
        WHEN SalesThisYearMonth IS NULL THEN -1 
        WHEN SalesLastYearMonth IS NULL THEN 1 
        WHEN SalesThisYearMonth = 0 then -1
        WHEN SalesLastYearMonth = 0 then 1
        ELSE ( SalesThisYearMonth - SalesLastYearMonth) / ABS(SalesLastYearMonth) END AS Growth
```

However, I'm really not sure about GROWTH there - not sure why you're dividing by SalesLastYearMonth.  In the case above this works, but if SalesLastYearMonth is -4, is dividing by 4 what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by a negative number:

```
SalesLastYearMonth = -1
```

You need to either check for it or return the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little suggestion. try using the ISNULL() function. if the value you select is NULL then you can give a default return value. As far as i know its much faster then CASE WHEN.

Comment: **`1`** This would require nested `ISNULL` calls, which would be less clear than a `CASE`. **`2`** Do you have any *data* to support the "faster" claim?